# Predefine field in class using several commands

Tags: c#, attributes, command, predefined-variables

Let's say I have this class with a constructor that fills the internal list with two entries:

```
class MyClass
{
    IList<int> someList;

    public MyClass()
    {
        someList = new List<int>();
        someList.Add(2);
        someList.Add(4);

        ... // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Now let's say I have several constructors which all do the same with the internal list (but differ in other aspects).

I would like to know if I can outsource the generation and filling of the list directly to the field, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    IList<int> someList = new List<int>(); someList.Add(2); someList.Add(4);
    // Does not compile.

    public MyClass()
    {
        ... // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call several commands in the field definition, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
IList<int> someList = new Func<List<int>>(() => { IList<int> l = new List<int>(); l.Add(2); l.Add(4); return l; })();
```

Explanation:

```
() => { IList<int> l = new List<int>(); l.Add(2); l.Add(4); return l; }
```

is a function taking no argument and returning an `IList<int>`, so it is a `Func<IList<int>>`.

Althoug the compiler knows this, it seems I explicitly have to state that fact via

```
new Func<IList<int>>(...)
```

to be able to call it later. The call is done as usual by putting two brackets `()` behind the `Func`.

Or to write it in a more readable way (then I don't even need the `new` keyword, but instead must make the `Func` static):

```
static Func<IList<int>> foo = () => { IList<int> l = new List<int>(); l.Add(2); l.Add(4); return l; };

IList<int> someList = foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-instantiated `IList` like this and add your values per accessing the Indexer:

```
IList<int> someList = new List<int>() { 2, 4 };
```

This will be initialization happens before the constructor is used.

---

#### Update 1

As OP mentioned in the comments, for `LinkedList<T>()` you have to use the constructor with some `IEnumarable` (in my Example an Array).

```
LinkedList<int> myList1 = new LinkedList<int>(new int[] {2,3,4});
```

---

#### Update 2

After reading your last comment, you're looking for `Fluent Interfaces` in your instantiation process. This is a method of chaining functions together and would look something like this:

```
Customer c1 = new Customer()  
                  .FirstName("matt")
                  .LastName("lastname")
                  .Sex("male")
                  .Address("austria");
```

<del>This functionality is not given by default in Collection Classes.You have to implement your own version of `IList<T>` for this.</del>

Lambda Expression is a way to achieve this, like your update shows...

Comment: No, I don't want to fill the list per constructor. I want to fill it before the constructor is called.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for `LinkedList`... Any idea on how to do it in general (not just `List`)?

Comment: @Kjara `LinkedList` helps you out with the constructor. :) You have to look where you can place the Indexers. Normally this works for every `IList<T>` Child.

Comment: You mean `LinkedList<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`? This needs a collection as input. I see that it is a workaround, but it takes unnecessarry memory. I could do this with all collections `K`: `ICollection<T> myCollection = new K(new T[] { // put my elements here })`, but I'm not very happy with it.

Comment: @Kjara I'm not sure what you want to achieve. The `LinkedList<T>` is a special kind of collection, which needs special handling. `IList<T>` instead is a simple thing and can be per Indexer filled.

Comment: I am most interested in a general way to queue several commands in the field definition. I mean, it could be that instead of filling a collection, I wanted to print stuff on the Console and then set a value to 42... I don't care about the usefulness of this example, I just want to know if C# allows this (and if yes, how).